Change order_updates flag at runtime through code for specific method execution
jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates is set to true by default in my application yaml.
I would like to set it to false for specific method execution which makes JPA repository calls to fetch as well as save DB data. This method is transactional and some how it is throwing exception when this flag is true. If it is false then everything works fine. I would like to use my existing entityManager/entityManagerFactory to get updated with the changed property.
I tried updating hibernate.order_updates property on session factory and entity manager factory but nothing seems to work.
what is the correct way to get this property updated and applied for execution?
I tried updating hibernate.order_updates property on session factory and entity manager factory but nothing seems to work.
what is the correct way to get this property updated and applied for execution?

I think you need to deal not with hibernate.order_updates but with your method that causes the error.

Is there anyway to set hibernate.order_updates at runtime through code? Error seems to be very weird Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Comparator.compare(Object, Object)" because "this.javatypeComparator" is null
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.compare(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:232)
at org.hibernate.type.BasicType.compare(BasicType.java:177)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityAction.compareTo(EntityAction.java:160)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityAction.compareTo(EntityAction.java:28)

Are you using a Hibernate custom type as your primary key?

yes primary key is custom type

I think there is no way to change the order_updates value at both Session and SesionFactory level since this parameter can only be set before SessionFactory is created in SessionFactoryBuilder.

You need to make another question regarding the specific error that occurs in your method.

hm.. ok ..Thanks

Disabling order_updates for just one method is not possible as it violates the Ordered Locking principle.
The Ordered Locking principle is a strategy used to prevent deadlocks by ensuring that resources are always locked in a consistent order across all threads or processes. This approach eliminates the possibility of circular wait conditions, which is one of the four necessary conditions for a deadlock to occur.
In essence, each thread must acquire resources in a predetermined, consistent sequence. If all threads adhere to this rule, circular dependencies are avoided, as no thread will ever have to wait for a resource held by another thread in an earlier position in the sequence.
For example, if resources A and B must be locked, all threads will lock A first, then B. This method is widely used in operating systems and concurrent programming to manage multiple locks and prevent deadlock situations effectively.
Therefore, the order_updates parameter can only be enabled for all application methods or for none.
For more detailed information, see Stanford University's CS 111: Operating Systems Principles lecture course.
